# I'm not getting a method description in swagger.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Swagger UI is created and looks descent except I can't get a description with my methods.

#### c# controller

```
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/me")]
    [SwaggerTag("Me")]
    public class MeController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetMe")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [SwaggerResponse(400, ControllerConstants.Http400Description, typeof(BadRequestMessage))]
        [SwaggerOperation("Retrieve the profile of the user", "test", OperationId = "test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            //code
        }
    }
```

#### startup.cs

```
services
    .AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
    {
        swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "<title>",
            Version = "1.0",
            Contact = new OpenApiContact()
            {
                Email = "<email>",
                Name = "<name>",
            },
            Description = "<description>",

        });
        swagger.AddServer(new OpenApiServer() { Url = "http://example.com" });
    };
services
    .AddApiVersioning(options => options.ReportApiVersions = true);
services
    .AddVersionedApiExplorer(
        options =>
        {
            options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
            options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });
services
    .AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

#### swagger.json (stripped)

I would expect the operation GetMe to have a summary/description as described in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "paths": {
    "/v1/me": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Me"
        ],
        "operationId": "GetMe",
        "responses": {
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/BadRequestMessage"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Me"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
}
```

### Update

I overlooked the EnableAnnotation method.
Simple case of [RTFM](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/0435a50131c2e09de7d9c7275e12eef7f7d90224/README.md#install-and-enable-annotations)

```
swagger.EnableAnnotations();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and Enable Annotations
Install the following Nuget package into your ASP.NET Core application.

```
Package Manager : Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations
CLI : dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations
```

In the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs, enable annotations within in the Swagger config block:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...

   c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

---

Taken from the manual [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/0435a50131c2e09de7d9c7275e12eef7f7d90224/README.md#install-and-enable-annotations).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like defined wrong *OperationId*. Originally it has already defined in *HttpGet* as *GetMe*.

Try to reference to already defined OperationId:

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "GetMe")]
[SwaggerOperation("Retrieve the profile of the user", "test", OperationId = "GetMe")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {..}
```

or define it only in *SwaggerOperation*:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerOperation("Retrieve the profile of the user", "test", OperationId = "GetMe")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {..}
```

Comment: I've tried both suggestions. The first gives the same result and the second removed the OperationId. I get the impression the SwaggerOperation is ignored as a whole. Must be something with configuration I've done wrong. Thanks for the suggestion.